# Rails | Cucumber | Capybara | click_button generates GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have a Cucumber Scenario with the following steps:

```
def create_admin
  @admin ||= FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
end

def sign_in
  visit '/admins/sign_in'
  fill_in "Email", with: @admin.email
  fill_in "Password", with: @admin.password
  save_and_open_page
  click_button "Sign in"
end

### Given ###
Given /^I exist as an admin$/ do
  create_admin
end

### WHEN ###
When /^I sign in with valid credentials$/ do
  sign_in
end


### THEN ###
Then /^I see a Sign out link$/ do
  page.should have_link "Sign out"
end
```

This is the test log for these actions:

```
Started GET "/admins/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-23 11:10:14 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (130.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 361ms (Views: 348.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/admins/sign_in?admin[email]=admin%40ca.coml&admin[password]=[FILTERED]&admin[remember_me]=0&commit=Sign+in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-23 11:10:14 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"admin"=>{"email"=>"admin@ca.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 6.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I'm completely confused by the fact that clicking the Sign in button seems to trigger a GET request.
Since this is working properly in development:

```
Started GET "/admins/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-23 11:08:26 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 35.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/admins/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-23 11:08:28 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nVSRKgJ33eZ1pW6FZGQhOFis/9/d/LS3Cshez4sBZYx2Fx/8mmmBfyB1C1VQZ84kA48zyhocu3MLlKxLaD0JlA==", "admin"=>{"email"=>"admin@ca.nl", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  Admin Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "admin@ca.nl"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "admins" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "sign_in_count" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "admins"."id" = $4  [["current_sign_in_at", "2017-08-23 09:08:28.326296"], ["sign_in_count", 2], ["updated_at", "2017-08-23 09:08:28.327254"], ["id", 2]]
   (7.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 181ms (ActiveRecord: 8.8ms)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using the 'rack_test' driver (as opposed to one of the JS enabled drivers that run an actual browser) and either haven't required 'capybara/rails' which tells the 'rack_test' driver to look for the `data-method` attribute and use that to set POST vs GET, or your form is written to require JS.

If neither of these is the case please post the HTML of the form